# Who's d survivor among 'N' ppl standing in a circle in an order 1 to N. 1 has a pistol,kills the adj(2) and passes to the next(3) and so on

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, this is how I tried to solve it! It worked till `Count=999`. But after that it returns a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

How can I solve it when `N=1000000` (1Million)?

PS: While I was posting this question it shows the same error when count=980 or something,It's strange! I checked it before and it worked!

```
    Count=input('Enter the number of people in the circle \n')
    Person=[]
    for i in range(1,int(Count)+1):
    Person.append(i)
    def alivePawn(temp,ref):
        preTemp=temp[:]
        del temp[1]
        newRef=list(set(ref)-set(list(set(preTemp)-set(temp))))
        newTemp=temp[1:]+list(set(newRef)-set(temp))+temp[:1]
        if len(newTemp)==2 and len(newRef)==2:
            print(newTemp[0])
        else:
            alivePawn(newTemp,newRef)
    alivePawn(Person,Person)
```

Comment: if I remeber correctly there was a `numberphile` video on that and the problem has an analytical solution. I'll see if I can find it

Comment: [The Josephus Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCsD3ZGzMgE&t=7s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best code for this problem,returns the answer for N=1 Million in 2 milliseconds:

```
count=int(input("enter the number of people in the circle \n"))
BiCount=int(bin(count)[2:]) #Converting to Binary
print(int(str(BiCount)[1:]+str(BiCount)[:1],2))
```

[The Josephus Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCsD3ZGzMgE&t=7s)